# Python (os): how to simulate pressing Enter while executing an external application

Tags: python, operating-system

I need to use an old-fashioned DOS/Windows executable (the source is not available). It uses two input files and produces one output file.

I have to run this several thousands times, using different input files. I wrote a simple python script looping over input files to automate this.

**The problem is that this exe finishes every single run with the immortal "press Enter".**

I start the script, keep the key pressed, 'returns' accumulate in the bufor and the script runs for a while producing several outputs.

Is there any more elegant way to proceed (i.e. without using the finger and staring at the monitor)?

I have already tried some obvious solutions (e.g. os.system('return'), os.system('\n')) but they do not work.

**Next day edit:**
@Eric, many thanks for the code, it works. I also thank others who contribute, and sorry for slopply written question and unformatted code in the comment (it was 3.30 am :)

Comment: You should provide code example

Comment: I use Linux, the code looks like this:
import os
import os
for i in range(1, 20001):
    a=str(i)
    command="wine executable.exe input"+a+".txt > output"+a+".txt"
    os.system(command)
    # executable.exe produces output1.txt and waits for Enter key

Comment: Edit your OP in order to publish the code properly :-)

Answer (score 2):

From the information in your comment, what I think you want is something like:

```
import subprocess

for i in range(1, 20001):
    command = "wine executable.exe input{number}.txt > output{number}.txt".format(number=i)
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    # send a newline
    p.communicate(input="\n")
```

Comment: needs to be: subprocess.Popen

Comment: Change to
```python
p.communicate(input='\n'.encode())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Python's `subprocess` module and run your executable with `Popen`.

Then you can send "enter" to the process with `communicate`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `os.system(‘\r\n’)`? I think that’s the newline character on windows.

Edit: Your answer also used a forward slash instead of a backslash--definitely try the other way too, unless that’s just a typo.

Comment: yes that should probly be a comment but I don’t have the reputation to comment yet...

Comment: It's wrong anyway. `os.system` isn't going to send a keystroke to another program.